# Attempting to use an incompatible return type - android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

Can someone help me with this error that I keep getting?
The program that I'm trying to make is online streaming radio.
I need to return the value "value" so i can use it in another java class.

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ch);

listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public int onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mPlayer.class);
        i.putExtra("name", ch.get(position));
        int value = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        startActivity(i);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs in this line:

```
int value = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

`getItemAtPosition()` returns an `Object`, so you must convert it to an `int` before assigning it to an `int` variable. You should do this only if you're sure that your `listView` contains integers, otherwise you'll get a `ClassCastException`. Do it like this:

```
int value = (int)listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Also, if you `startActivity()` before using the `value` anywhere, then it does not make much sense in getting it. Use `putExtra` to pass it to your next activity if you wish to use it there.

Comment: tried that didn't work...note that it was void by default before i change it to integer.

Comment: You need to explain to me what you're trying to make happen. Also what does your listview contain?

Comment: my listview contain numbers....and i want the position of the element of listview when tapped to use it in another class

Comment: Just pass the `position` in your intent via `putExtra` then. No need to call `getItemAtPosition`. If you need the number, than get it like this and still pass it. What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: No problem at all. Enjoy coding! :)